# Jquery Ajax Call security in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I have my application using jQuery Ajax posts for saving and updating records.

All my posts are using JSON.stringify like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Vendor/SaveProvider")/',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(
                 {

                     jsonProvider: ko.toJSON(appViewModel.provider),
                     jsonAddresses: ko.toJSON(appViewModel.addresses),
                     jsonContacts: ko.toJSON(appViewModel.contacts)
                 }),
```

I was reading that ASP.NET MVC comes with a **ValidateAntiForgeryToken** filter for controllers calls but I can't find any resource on how to make it work using Jquery Ajax and JSON.stringify....

So, I came into this idea and would like to know if its ok...

I know that jQuery.Ajax let you send extra header information, so I will do this:

1. Will create a custom filter controller
2. This filter will check if my current session is not NULL and will retrive a "sessionlogid" (GUID) that was created when the user first login into the web app.
3. Will get the custom header value that was sent with Jquery Ajax post that contains that
   "sessionlogid" and will see if its the same value.
4. If its same value then will let the controller go, if not will send an error.

My filter should look like this:

```
public class ValidateAjaxSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["sessionlogid"] == null ||
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["sessionlogid"] != Session["sessionlogid"])
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid Request", new Exception());
        }
    }
}
```

Does this make sense or is there any better way to protect the app?

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: why do you do stringify and just leave it as is ?

Comment: Because Im using knockout and seems is the only way the controller get the info.

Answer (score 0):

If its a post use

```
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

If its a get use

```
[Authorize]
```

You can also use this custom attribute

```
public class HttpAjaxRequestAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            throw new Exception("This action " + methodInfo.Name + " can only be called via an Ajax request");
        }
        return true;
    }
}

Then decorate your action as below
[Authorize]
[HttpAjaxRequest]
public ActionResult FillCity(int State)
{
    //code here
}
```